# How much money does Homer make?

Tags: the-simpsons

Homer works as a full time nuclear safety inspector, with no other notable sources of income. How much money does he make in total?

There are many ways to work this out, and for such a long-running series set in a fictional universe, many answers could be contradictory, so please state your sources and methods.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, regarding his job as a nuclear safety inspector, according to [this site](http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Homer%27s_jobs):

> In the episode "Much Apu About Nothing", Homer's paycheck is revealed to the world when he looks at the check and sees his pay is "drastically" short. It appears as an itemized check with the following:
>
> Springfield Power Company
>
> Employee: Homer J Simpson
>
> Sector 7G
>
> 40HRS PAY
>
> Fed W/H........... $56.25
>
> Bear Patrol Tax........$5.00
>
> FICA..................$36.34
>
> State W/H..........$10.45
>
> Municipal Tax.....$9.37
>
> Net Pay...........................................................................$362.19
>
> When this is stretched over a year, **it appears that Homer brings home $24,395.80 before deductions and $18,833.88 after deductions.** It doesn't seem like he is getting what he deserves as a Nuclear Safety Inspector. Though given the plant's less than stellar conditions this might be true for all other employees. However, in the episode *American History X-cellent*, Carl exclaims to Homer, "Homer, that's a $60,000 bottle of wine!", which Homer, who is drinking the wine, replies "Woohoo! I'm drinking my salary!" which suggests that's his actual salary.

But I'm not sure he has 'no other notable sources of income', as you stated. You seem to forget he has other jobs like *every other week*; some, however brief, are pretty lucrative. In his nuclear plant alone, he's also been [manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiss_Kiss,_Bang_Bangalore), [executive vice president](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weekend_at_Burnsie%27s) and even [CEO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C.E.D%27oh). Outside it, he's been [Sanitation Commissioner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trash_of_the_Titans), [astronaut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Space_Homer) and [mayor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Tale_of_Two_Springfields). And he might *still* be earning residual incomes and royalties from some of his other jobs (like [movie producer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyond_Blunderdome) and [the voice of Poochie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Itchy_&_Scratchy_&_Poochie_Show)).

Ultimately, though, since Homer must be wasting away any extra money he comes by thanks to his foolhardy nature, and since this is a sitcom that must return to the status quo each week and maintain the Simpsons as a blue-collar family, I'd say that paycheck noted above would be as good a guess as any for a cartoon show that's [not exactly realistic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddlesore_Galactica).

Comment: I can't believe you didn't mention Mr. Plow...